# Force apt or apt-get to return error code on warning

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, update-manager

`apt-get` and `apt` are exiting with `0` instead of an error code when they cant resolve a repository. I'd like to get a non-zero in this case (and for warnings generally).

e.g.

```
# apt-get update
Err:1 https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Note the output contains `Err:` and `W:` so I'd expect this to be an error with non-zero exit code, but it seems like it's just considered to be a warning since the exit code is `0`...? Either way I'd like to know how to get an error code instead of zero for the above example and for warnings generally. Yes I could grep for `W:` or `Err:` but I'd like the error code if possible.

Comment: Try this: [apt-get update exit status](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/653377/65304)

Comment: `# apt-get update -o APT::Update::Error-Mode=any`, still showed warnings and error but still exited `0`

Answer (score 0):

#### You can try apt "replacement": [nala](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala)

##### Installation instruction: https://gitlab.com/volian/nala/-/wikis/Installation

Nala have non-zero exit code when some problem occurred, also write problematic part with different color and error part repeat at end of update output...

##### Running update is same as with apt, but nala have structured output:

`sudo nala update`

##### Or if you don't want structured output:

`sudo nala update --raw-dpkg`